# VS Code Task Runner failing to reflect tasks.json file changes if on mapped network drive

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-7-x64

**Summary:** Changes I make to a `tasks.json` file are not reflected when I execute a *ctrl-shift-B* command if the working directory is on a mapped network drive.  How can I fix this problem? (when all files are local everything works as expected)

**Setup for replication:**

1) make folder for project

2) make simple python file

```
print("hello")
```

3) make `.vscode` sub-directory with `tasks.json` containing (roughly)

```
{
    // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["${fileBasename}"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

4) copy file structure to my mapped network drive (a local Synology NAS).

Now when I make changes to the tasks.json and save it I can see the file is indeed updated by opening it in another editor. **However**, if I try to build task with ctrl-shift-B, it uses the version of the file present when i opened vscode, not the updated version.

If I exit out of VS Code and re-open it,  VS Code will use the updated copy.

Comment: confirmed as a bug [github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5451